# Problem with using allrunes together with lettrine and a custom LettrineFontHook

Tags: fonts, xetex, unicode

I want to use the `allrunes` package to import a certain unicode character from the runic set.

I'm using `lettrine` with a custom `\LettrineFontHook` to set it to a custom color:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lettrine}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{DropCapViolet} {HTML} {9090C0}
\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\rmfamily\mdseries\color{DropCapViolet}}
% \usepackage{allrunes}

\begin{document}

\lettrine[lhang=0.17]{H}{ello}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, if I uncomment the `\usepackage{allrunes}` entry, I'm getting the following error:

```
Argument of \@tempc has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.12 \lettrine[lhang=0.17]{H}{ello}
```

Is there a way of fixing this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(adding my own answer, since I managed to work around it!)

I googled those two things together (the error + "allrunes"), and I found this single [forum post](https://www.guitex.org/home/en/forum/5-tex-e-latex/58493-runico-allrunes-risolto) (in Italian!) with a similar issue.

One of the replies suggested adding the following:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\letcs\xmdseries{mdseries }
\usepackage{allrunes}
\cslet{mdseries }\xmdseries
```

After adding, and changing `\mdseries` to `\xmdseries` inside my `\LettrineFontHook` command, the error went away and everything built successfully!